# datetime conversion not working

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I am trying to convert a datetime in the following format;

```
Mar 30 19:34:33  2013
```

to a set format I defined. Despite using the correct syntax it fails to convert giving an error:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Here is the code:

```
Dim theDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(contentDate, "MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
newDate = theDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Is there something I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two spaces before the year but only one in the format string. You could use

```
Dim theDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(contentDate, "MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces)
```